# Echoing what command is running in shell script

Tags: shell, echo

Is it possible to echo out what command is being run in a shell script?

(Without put the -X in the sheabang to turn on the debuggin mode. This is not part of a debugging process)

thanks

[Edit: more details]

Suppose I have a script like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

clear
cd ~/home/
```

How do I have the two commands that are executed (`cd` and `clear`) printed to the console?

Comment: No. This is exactly what `-x` is for.

Comment: If you don't want to use `-x`, consider `-v` instead.

Comment: @larsmans: I would've marked your comment as the answer :), but didn't know how to.

Comment: @OneTwoThree: posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my version of `/bin/sh` (the Debian Almquist Shell, dash), there's no other way than `-x` to get this behavior. Echoing commands is also the *only* effect of `-x`, so I see no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $0
```

That will echo the first word in the command line. If you specified a relative path, such as "./bin/test", that will show the whole path, so you may want:

```
echo $(basename $0)
```

That will just echo "test", instead of "./bin/test".

It's very common for scripts to use $0 in error messages, rather than hard coding the name, because the program could be renamed or called from a symlink.

Comment: All good info. But I think the O.P. is looking to echo that a cmd is running further down in the script. I.E. `#!/bin/bash;cmd1; echo cmd2; cmd2; cmd3`. Good luck to all.

Comment: Uhm, I didn't mean to print out the name of the script ($0).

Comment: "echo $0" does exactly what you asked: echoes the command being run. What do you want? To echo the command that's going to be run? Echo the command being run in another process?

Comment: I don't think you understand what I asked for. (I've editted the question with more details)

Comment: I guess I just need more context of why you'd want to do this outside of a debugging context. You could create a list of commands and arguments and iterate over it...